# Joomla 3, Protostar Template,NAV-COLLAPSE IS NOT HAPPENING

Tags: joomla

I have developed a Responsive website in Joomla 3 using the protostar template as default. Its a responsive page. I have created  Main menus. I am trying to resize the Screen to 480 (mobile) the menus are not changing into Drop Down. 
NAV-COLLAPSE DOESN'T HAPPEN. even though i have given @ media.

If i Change the template to ISIS Template nav-collapse works.

my css:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Would really like to know if i can write a Java Script for The Nav-collapse

Comment: Are you recompiling the css and checking the results?  Sometimes I have had problems where a new LESS file I had added was not being compiled. You don't need to write javascript, that's why Bootstrap exists.   Is it me or are you missing a }?   Do you mean you are making the same change to ISIS?

Comment: No isis by default is making the menu as drop down list

Comment: ISIS is an administrator template and does no use the same menu as the front end.  The protostar template in the front end will give you a horizontal drop down if you use the correct class.  On the advanced tab for Menu Class Suffix put `  nav-pills`  ( the space is important).

Comment: I have already done that but its not happening . On the advanced tab for menu i have kept ' nav-pills' but still it doesnt function.